# Permit one of the given schemas

Tags: python, yaml, schema, cerberus

I am using Cerberus to validate some YAML files that might look like this:

**`fleet.yml`**

```
fleet_city: "New York"
vehicles:
  vehicle_1:
    car:
      # License plate required for car
      license_plate: "ABC123"
      cargo: 10

  vehicle_2:
    # All vehicle types can have optional remarks block
    remarks:
      active: true

    car:
      license_plate: "XYZ789"
      # Cargo is optional

  # Vehicle names (dict keys) are arbitrary
  cool_ride:
    remarks:
      active: false

    boat:
      # Required
      seaworthy: true

      # not required
      sails: 3
```

The general structure is that there are some file-wide values like `fleet_city`, and then a block called `vehicles`. The latter is a dictionary with vehicle names as keys. Every vehicle type has its own schema, although they're all dictionaries. I came up with this schema to formalize this:

**`schema.yml`**

```
fleet_city: 
  type: string

vehicles:
  type: dict

  keysrules:
    # Vehicle name constraints
    type: string
    regex: '[A-Za-z\d_]+'

  valuesrules:
    type: dict

    schema:
      # Optional remarks block
      remarks:
        type: dict

      # Car schema
      car:
        schema:
          license_plate:
            type: string
            required: true

          cargo:
            type: integer
            required: false

      # Boat schema
      boat:
        schema:
          seaworthy:
            type: boolean
            required: true

          propulsion:
            type: dict

            schema:
              sails:
                type: integer
                required: false
```

Which I can test with:

```
import yaml
from cerberus import Validator

with open('schema.yml') as f:
    schema = yaml.safe_load(f)
v = Validator(schema)

with open('fleet.yml') as f:
    fleet = yaml.safe_load(f)

print(v.validate(fleet))
print(v.errors)
```

Which correctly returns `True`. However, in the input every vehicle is supposed to have one type (either one `car` block or one `boat` block, not both). This rule is not reflected in the schema above. I tried to add it like so:

**`schema2.yml`**

```
fleet_city: 
  type: string

vehicles:
  type: dict

  keysrules:
    # Vehicle name constraints
    type: string
    regex: '[A-Za-z\d_]+'

  valuesrules:
    type: dict

    schema:
      # Optional remarks block
      remarks:
        type: dict

      oneof_schema:
        # Car schema
      - car:
        schema:
          license_plate:
            type: string
            required: true

          cargo:
            type: integer
            required: false

        # Boat schema
      - boat:
        schema:
          seaworthy:
            type: boolean
            required: true

          propulsion:
            type: dict

            schema:
              sails:
                type: integer
                required: false
```

From what I can tell, I have followed the [syntax given in the docs](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules) but `schema2.yml` causes:

```
cerberus.schema.SchemaError: {'vehicles': [{'valuesrules': [{'schema': ['no definitions validate', {'anyof definition 0': [{'oneof': ['must be of dict type']}], 'anyof definition 1': [{'oneof': [{'schema': ['no definitions validate', 'no definitions validate', {'anyof definition 0': [{'car': ['null value not allowed'], 'schema': [{'cargo': ['unknown rule'], 'license_plate': ['unknown rule'], 'propulsion': ['unknown rule'], 'seaworthy': ['unknown rule']}], 'boat': ['null value not allowed']}], 'anyof definition 1': [{'car': ['unknown rule'], 'boat': ['unknown rule']}]}]}], 'remarks': ['unknown rule']}]}]}]}]}
```

Which doesn't really help.

One workaround is to use [`excludes`](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#excludes) for `car` in `boat` and vice versa, but that approach will fall apart if we have not just 2 vehicle types but many.

What is the issue in my `schema2.yml` and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe someone would invest time in your question if you narrowed it down to a less voluminous example.

Comment: @funky-future What details do you think can be removed?